# Density matrix for system and surroundings

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

In my QM lecture it was claimed that if you have a system with degrees freedom $\vec{s}$ and its surroundings which have degrees of freedom $\vec{u}$ then every density matrix for the combined system can be expressed as

$$ \hat\rho = \sum_{\vec{u}} \sum_{\vec{s}} p_{\vec{u}, \vec{s}} \left|\vec{u}, \vec{s} \right> \left< \vec{u}, \vec{s}\right|$$

(I suppose that the sum is should range over orthonormal bases $\{\left| u \right> \}$ and $\{\left| s \right> \}$.)

To me it seems that this is not general enough to express all possible density matrices. Is that right or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

> To me it seems that this is not general enough to express all possible density matrices. Is that right or am I missing something?

You are correct. The most general density matrix should read
$$
\hat\rho = \sum_{\vec{u},\vec{s},\vec{u}',\vec{s}'} p_{\vec{u}, \vec{s},\vec{u}',\vec{s}'} \left|\vec{u}, \vec{s} \middle> \middle< \vec{u}', \vec{s}'\right|,
$$
with $|\vec u⟩$ and $|\vec s⟩$ running over orthonormal bases for the environment and the system, respectively, with the requirements that
$$
p_{\vec{u}, \vec{s},\vec{u}',\vec{s}'} = p_{\vec{u}', \vec{s}',\vec{u},\vec{s}}^{\ \ast}
$$
for hermiticity, 
$$
\sum_{\vec{u},\vec{s}} p_{\vec{u}, \vec{s},\vec{u},\vec{s}} = 1
$$
for unit trace, as well as positive-semidefiniteness on the matrix.

Comment: Almost. You can impose some conditions on that parameter since $\rho$ is hermitian, positive semidefinite and has unit trace.

Comment: @both I thought that went without saying, but you're both correct.

Comment: I think this still isn't enough for positive-semidefiniteness, $\mathrm{diag}(1, 1, 0, -1)$ satisfies your conditions

Comment: @0x539 The matrix needs to be positive-semidefinite, which is already explicitly called for in this answer. Your example does not fall into the class described here.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty ah, the last part is supposed to mean that you require the matrix to be positive definite (and not that positive-definiteness follows from the previous two requirements)

Comment: Interesting.  Since $\rho$ is hermitian it can be diagonalized and thus *can* be expressed in the form given by the OP.  The question then is: what basis is used?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero that would only be the case if every eigenvector of every density matrix were a product state, which isn't true at all

Comment: @GabrielGolfetti Right: I see your point.  I just hadn’t understood the question in quite the same way.